# bad URI or cross-site access not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, cross-site

In my codeigniter site i used edwardian script font.

But when i used this i got this error in bug and site design breaked :

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Edwardian Script" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
```

The site is working perfectly before changing the server.

That means the client moved the site into new server for ssl feature,after that codeigniter site not working correctly.

I got the above error in bug.

So how can i solve this?

Comment: Is the font file stored at another domain?

Comment: @ matthias , no it is stored in the same domain...

Comment: Also under the same port? The error "cross-site access" indicates that you are trying to download the font from another host. Maybe you are downloading it via HTTP from an HTTPS site.

Comment: @ matthias, how can i check that...?

Comment: @ matthias , the client didnot do any modifications he just moved the site into https, If there is any settings in codeigniter as http ..?

Comment: That depends on how you include the font in your webpage. Are you declaring the fonts via CSS or are you downloading the fonts via the server and return an image?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15446/discussion-between-mariya-davis-and-matthias-p)

Comment: @ matthias, i downloaded and uploaded it in the same domain and the font declared via css..

Comment: @ Matthias , i found that in config.php page the `base_url` decalred as `http` so i changed it as `https` .Now the css font problem corrected.But my site is not working perfectly...

Comment: @ Matthias, there have some js and css files are included in the home page  as `http` ,if there is any problem that?

Answer (score -1):

In application/config/config.php make sure the below is set

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

Should find this resolves your issue.